# Training the saving deep learning model in Pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I have a deep learning model in pytorch (here I provide a simple overview of that). Since I have to run the model each day. I want to save the model in the previous day and then I train the saved model for small number of epochs (3-4) epochs more. Here is the model:

```
class NET(nn.Module):
    
    def forward(self, y, par):

    def test(self, y, num_samples):


    
def train_batch(model, optimizer, device):
    model.train()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    length = float(batch.size(0))
    ...
    return loss1

def trainv(model, device, epochs, train_iterator, optimizer, validate_iterator):

    for epoch in range(epochs):  
        
        for local_batch, local_labels in train_iterator:
            
            train_loss = train_batch(model, optimizer, device)

        validate_loss = runs_for_validate(validate_iterator, n_samples)  # check on validate data

    return train_losses, validate_loss



model              = NET(inputs).to(device)

optimizer          = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr =learning_rate )

train_losses, validate_loss = train(model, device, epochs, train_iterator, optimizer, validate_iterator)
```

My problem is that I dont know how to save the model and then again loading the **saved model to train with more epochs.**
previously I could save the `model.state_dict()` in '.pt' and can load it, but it seems it does not work here. I already saw this post, [How can I save my training progress in PyTorch for a certain batch no.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63655048/how-can-i-save-my-training-progress-in-pytorch-for-a-certain-batch-no) , however I dont know which format I should save the model? and also when I should save the model? Could you please help me with this?

Comment: It's also a good practice to save the model at the end of training and during the training process if the validation loss improves.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the entire model, including the model architecture and its current state, by passing in the model object to the function.

```
torch.save(model, "model.pt")
```

You can save the model's state dictionary, which contains the model's parameters, separately.

```
torch.save(model.state_dict(), "model_state.pt")
```

You can load the model by using the torch.load function, passing in the path of the saved model.

```
model = torch.load("model.pt")
```

You can also load the state dictionary separately and use it to load the model's parameters.

```
state_dict = torch.load("model_state.pt")
model.load_state_dict(state_dict)
```

you can try like

```
class NET(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, inputs):
        super(NET, self).__init__()
        self.inputs = inputs

    def forward(self, y, par):
        # Your forward pass here
        pass

    def test(self, y, num_samples):
        # Your test function here
        pass

def train_batch(model, optimizer, device):
    model.train()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    length = float(batch.size(0))
    ...
    return loss1

def trainv(model, device, epochs, train_iterator, optimizer, validate_iterator, save_path):

    best_loss = float('inf')

    for epoch in range(epochs):  
        
        for local_batch, local_labels in train_iterator:
            train_loss = train_batch(model, optimizer, device)

        validate_loss = runs_for_validate(validate_iterator, n_samples)  # check on validate data

        # Save the model if the validation loss improves
        if validate_loss < best_loss:
            best_loss = validate_loss
            torch.save(model.state_dict(), save_path)
    return train_losses, validate_loss

def load_model(model, load_path, device):
    state_dict = torch.load(load_path, map_location=device)
    model.load_state_dict(state_dict)
    return model

# Initialize the model
model = NET(inputs).to(device)

# Load the model if a save path is provided
if load_path is not None:
    model = load_model(model, load_path, device)

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr =learning_rate )

train_losses, validate_loss = trainv(model, device, epochs, train_iterator, optimizer, validate_iterator, save_path)
```

Comment: With this way, how I can train the model again? I mean, where I should put this lines of code?

Comment: check the updated code above